# Get definition without comments in (lib)clang

Tags: clang, libclang

Suppose I have the variable definition `int x = MACRO(5)       /* HOHO */ + 25;` and have access to `x`'s CXCursor in libclang. I want to get the definition without the additional spaces and without the comment. I know how to get the extents of the cursor, but suppose I use the obtained start/end locations to obtain the definition string from the source file, does (lib)clang have any helper function for removing comments? I can write one myself (does not seem to be that hard), but thought maybe there already exists one.

EDIT: Actually, it may actually be quite hard to write one myself.. one thing I forgot is that I also have to take strings into account: `char* str = "\* abcde " \* comment */;`